# How do I make a 3 column table with specific preferences

Tags: html, css, resize, html-table

I am currently designing a website and I would like to have it exactly the same on the HTML. One part is the header logo and I would like to have full support for widescreen monitors so I created a table with 3 columns, starting from the left is the white background to extend the logo design, the middle one is the logo with fixed width, column on the right is the dark denim blue with bright red background, also as a purpose to fit in with the logo, two sides should have the same width and in result that the middle column would stay in the middle.

Here's how it looks like:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/76AF2.png

Here's how I want it to work:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/SO7uI.png

But I can't manage to make those two sides resize themselves according to the browser's screen width. I know how to repeat the image so it looks like it is expanding(background-repeat: repeat-x;) and on the same size(background-size: contain;), no matter what kind of value I put in the CSS(width: auto;) or (width: 100%;) or (width: *;), it simply just don't work.

Please help me, thank you so much for your patience.

Comment: how you set the width of those two columns?

Comment: You should show the HTML you have so far. What you are writing there is unclear; for instance I don't know what the problem is with your current page; it looks like it does what you want! If your table is 100% and your middle column has a fixed width, `width:auto` (or no width at all) would do the trick.

Comment: However, you shouldn't use tables for layout purposes; that's not what they are for.

Comment: Use [div](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_div.asp) for layout and table for only tables... Will save you from sins...

Comment: There was a useful answer saying that I should use <table> inside a <td> with 3 tds in it. Could the person who provides this answer reupload it again? I want to click the useful button. It worked in firefox but not safari though. Thanks so much

Answer (score 0):

If you're *really* using a table... and I understand your question. I think this is close to what you're looking for.

```
<table style="width:100%;border:1px solid black"">
    <tr>
        <td style="border: 1px solid black;">left</td>
        <td style="width:860px;border: 1px solid black;">middle</td>
        <td style="border: 1px solid black;">right</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Did you try the above? Can you provide a sample of your html and css?